# Return response object in event listener not working when triggered in controller plugin

Tags: zend-framework2

I implemented a shared event listener that manipulates and returns the response object with an error template showing the message of the triggered error code. (I'm not talking about throwing exceptions and catching them in a dispatch.error listener!)

This works fine when I call this event in a controller action. However, when I trigger my error event in a controller plugin that is called in the onDispatch method of the controller, only the status code is set correctly. But the called action is fully executed and no error page is shown.

I have absolutely no idea why this happens and I hope, someone is able to explain me the dispatch/event triggering/short circuiting/returning response issue here.

Following extracts might give you an impression of my code:

Listener:

```
class SharedErrorListener implements SharedListenerAggregateInterface {
  ...

  public myErrorFunction(EventInterface $e) {
    // get error code
    // set status code to injected response object
    // add error template to injected view model
    // return response
  }
}
```

Random controller action (works fine):

```
  return $this->getEventManager()->trigger('error', $this, array(
    'errorCode' => my_error_code
  ));
```

onDispatch() of controller:

```
// call plugin, if return value given return it (response must be returned?!).
$r= $this->plugin('myplugin')->doIt();
if (isset($r)) {
  return $r;
}
```

class myplugin doIt() where error is triggered, but error template not showing up:

```
  return $this->getController()->getEventManager()->trigger('error', $this, array(
    'errorCode' => my_error_code
  ));
```

As the code in the controller and the controller plugin ist pretty much the same, I think it must depend on some application state. I did a lot of research, but couldn't find, what the problem might be. But as the event is triggered correctly and also the right status code is set to the response, I am just very confused. I don't want to implement an ErrorController (which would allow to call a redirect), because I think the solution via EventManager is actually very nice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm too busy to actually read all the above, but from what my impression is, this code-snipped may actually help you out:

```
$trigger = $this->getEventManager()->trigger(self::EVENT_IDENTITY_GET, $identity);
if ($trigger instanceof ResponseCollection && !is_null($trigger->last())) {
    return $trigger->last();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, very much appreciated. I indeed didn't realize that I was returning an instance of ResponseCollection instead of Response. However, if I use this code in my action, I just receive a blank page (it works returning the ResponseCollection), same happens in the controller plugin. But nonetheless its a good hint, i'll look deeper into it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem here. By returning the response during the onDispatch process, the onDispatch() of the AbstractActionController wasn't called. In that function the return value of the controller action, e.g. the view model, is set as "result" of the MvcEvent. I just had to set the template that was set in the listener as the result for the event:

```
$r = $this->plugin('my_plugin')->doIt();

if ($r instanceof ResponseCollection) {
  $e->setResult($this->getServiceLocator()->get('view_manager')->getViewModel()->getChildren());
  return $r;
}
```

Hope this helps someone.